# Profiling an OpenMP program with explicit openMP tasks

Tags: c, parallel-processing, profiling, scheduled-tasks, openmp

As part of my reserach I am looking for alternatives to profile an OpenMP code with explicit tasks (as per OpenMP 3.0). My main objective is to study the amount of overhead incurred when tasks are lying idle at a global barrier (such as a taskwait), prior to being scheduled and executed.

I looked into using the latest version of TAU, which has support for Opari which in turn instruments the source code to produce profiling statistic. Unfortunately since it instruments the source code, this is leading to large amount of overhead in program execution.

Tools like Gprof and PGprof do not provide the detail I am looking for. I have already tried and tested with them.

I am looking for a tool, which can help me in profiling an OpenMP program with tasks by levying minimum overhead. I am tempted to look into HPCToolkit and Scalasca, but I am not sure if they provide support for OpenMP tasks.

Looking for directions and your suggestions.
Thanks!!

Comment: Profiling of OpenMP tasks is an active research field right now, which means that there are not many production quality tools that can do it to the full extent. My colleagues are working on it within the [Score-P](http://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p/) project - may be you should take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [LIKWID](https://code.google.com/p/likwid/) = Like I Knew What I’m Doing.
It is very reliable and free.